# jQuery click event fires on second and every other click but not on first

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

When I click first time on my link jQuery doesn't work, but every other time I click, it works.
I have link which leads me to the same page but adding some GET vaules. And then I want to take those values and print something on my popup box, which needs to be visible on click. So this is my code.
HTML

```
        <div id="pop_background"></div>

        <div id="pop_box">
            <span id="close">&times;</span>
            <?php
                stampa_lokala($_GET['ime']);
            ?>
        </div>
```

PHP
//setting link with element from database which gives, GET value and has name, so I can have inner link towards it

```
<a href="?ime=<?php echo $lokal_ime;?>#<?php echo $lokal_ime;?>" 
            class="open_box"  name="<?php echo $lokal_ime;?>"><?php echo $lokal_ime;?></a>
```

jQuery //setting popup box

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.open_box').click(function(){
                    setTimeout(function(){$('#pop_background').fadeIn();
                    $('#pop_box').fadeIn();
                    return false;}, 200);
            });
    });
```

CSS

```
.open_box{
position: relative;
padding-top: 150px;
}
#pop_background{
position:fixed;
width:100%;
height:900px;
top:0;
left:0;
background:#000;
opacity:0.8;
z-index:1000;
cursor:pointer;
display:none;
}
#pop_box{
position:fixed;
background:white;
width: auto;
height: auto;
max-width: 50%;
margin-left: -27%;
margin-top: -20%;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
padding:10px;
z-index: 1500;
display:none;
}
#close{
width:30px;
height:30px;
border-radius: 50%;
border: 1px solid #999;
text-align: center;
line-height:30px;
font-size:30px;
float:right;
}
```

HTML from page from one element from db

```
<section class="dogadjaji">
            <h3>Događaji</h3>
            <section class="lijevi"><div><table id="okvir"><tr><td>                     
                    <a href="?ime=Cheers#Cheers" 
                                class="open_box"  name="Cheers">Cheers</a>
                    <img src="slike\kuba.jpg">
                    <p class="izvodjac">Kuba</p>
                    <p class="time">21:00 <br />18.07.2016</p></td></tr></table></div></section>
</section>
```

Comment: It might be possible the first click event is captured by some other scripts/services. You must ensure if in you have not binded the click event for " open_box  " elsewhere.

Comment: not that I'm aware of, the problem is that I need to use setTimeout, because I need to set GET values and then run jQuery click event, so I can print element from db

Comment: Please check this code hopefully that will help you.https://fiddle.jshell.net/zw2xr098/

Comment: Please could you share your CSS ?

Comment: I added CSS for you

Comment: When I set this link just like <a href="#" ..>, popup works every time, but I really need that link for my GET values...

Comment: return false inside of the setTimeout does nothing. Is it supposed to be outside the timeout to cancel the click?

Comment: No, I can see now that I can delete it. But still, when I delete setTimeout and return false, there is still the same problem. Not working on first click

Comment: can you post your complete generated html? not php

Comment: Try stopping propagation. event.stopPropagation();  $('.open_box').click(function(e){ e.stopPropagation(); //further code

Comment: How can I call php function "stampa_lokala($_GET['ime'])"  on .click()? I think that that's the problem. Because it can't work just like calling it in div "open_box"...